# Index of vector in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In Clojure Java interop gives us `.indexOf`, but ClojureScript doesn't have that. How do I get the index of an item in a vector?

```
(def items [:a :b :c])

;; Clojure
(.indexOf items :a) ; => 0

;; ClojureScript
;; ???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the vector into an array. http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/to-array

I'm unsure of what the perf is on this. :)

```
cljs.user=> (.indexOf (to-array [:a :b]) :b)
=> 1
```

Comment: It looks to me like to-array is not lazy. You may be better of with the one of the implementations in the other answers. Try (.indexOf (to-array (iterate inc 0)) 2)

Comment: This doesn't work in Clojurescript, does it? See this rejected bug report: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-996

On CLJS 1.7, `(.indexOf (to-array [:a :b]) :b)` returns `-1`

Answer (score 9):

Here is an explicitly recursive answer. I am hoping for a better answer though!

```
(defn index-of [s v]
  (loop [idx 0 items s]
    (cond
      (empty? items) nil
      (= v (first items)) idx
      :else (recur (inc idx) (rest items)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

another option (return nil if not-found)

```
(defn index-of [coll value]
  (some (fn [[idx item]] (if (= value item) idx))
        (map-indexed vector coll)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Clojurescript doesn't appear to have an explicit `index-of` method (at least not one that I can find with a reasonable amount of googling).

For your example you could map the clojurescript data structures to javascript arrays and use the native javascript `.indexOf`

```
=> (.indexOf (clj->js [:a :b :c :d]) (clj->js :c))
=> 2
```

But there are 2 problems with this, firstly you have to leave the world of persistent data structures which is a big part of what makes clojurescript great, but the bigger problem is that it doesn't work on reference types. E.g.

```
=> (.indexOf (clj->js [{:a :b} {:c :d}]) (clj->js {:c :d}))
=> -1
```

so it's of limited use.

Your own recursive solution is a fine one under the circumstances. If you want something more functional you could do:

```
(defn index-of [coll v]
  (let [i (count (take-while #(not= v %) coll))]
    (when (or (< i (count coll)) 
            (= v (last coll)))
      i)))
```